# send command with char[] fields from C# to C++ via WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

We have a C++ hardware control software in Linux with socket communication to outside, and we are adding a C# application in Windows to send commands to that C++ software via WCF (Net.TCP) (.Net 3.5 or 4).

The commands/protocols defined contain a header and data.

There are some `char[]` fields inside the protocol structure.

The `char` in C# is 2 bytes, but the `char` defined in our protocol is 1 byte `char`.

How can I make them compatible? Any existing utility library can do the conversion for me?

Comment: `net.tcp` only works between two .NET programs. It's not an interop binding.

Comment: somebody in this project wants to use WCF because customer's GUI is C# application. So this WCF is a middleware between our customer's GUI and our existing control software (C++ with socket). I am learning WCF so I may choose a wrong protocol?

Comment: There is no standard WCF protocol that translates to simple sockets. You can create one, however. But if you need to do sockets, you might be better off sticking to the .NET sockets classes.

Answer (score 2):

Much easier to use plain sockets in .NET as WCF's sockets are unpredictable and aren't cross-platform. To convert a string in C# to C++ buffer use Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string)

Comment: Also take care with big/little endian issues if the target controller is non-Intel